# Automatically selected columns in ASPxGridView

Tags: devexpress, selected, aspxgridview

I have 3 nested ASPxGridViews in my project. One is the master grid, the other ones are detail grid connected with primary/foreign key. When I click the new button in a detail grid, the columns in the form comes totally blank. But I want some columns which have ParentID to be automatically selected because I already selected that in its master grid. Here is a specific example:

I have a master grid which shows companies. This grid has a detail grid which shows departments belonging to these companies. I chose one of the companies and departments which blongs to it appeared in the detail grid. Then I cliked new button to create a new department data. But in the form, company combobox column is blank while it should be automatically selected. I have to choose the same company in this combobox again.

I couldn't find anything in DevExpress forums about this problem. I appreciate if you help.

Comment: What about setting it's value in the RowUpdating event? Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: to show using CellEditorInitialize:

```
protected void gvDepartments_CellEditorInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewEditorEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as ASPxGridView;

    if (grid == null || !grid.IsNewRowEditing)return;
    if (!e.Column.FieldName.Equals("Company")) return;

    (e.Editor as ASPxComboBox).SelectedValue =  grid.GetMasterRowKeyValue();
}
```

---

`gridView.GetMasterRowKeyValue()` on a detail grid gives you he `KeyValue` of the Master Grid. You can use this in `HtmlRowCreated` or `CellEditorInitialize` Event on your detail grid to get the Master key field (company id in yourcase), and have the combobox in the Edit Form selected as shown below:

```
protected void gvDepartments_HtmlRowCreated(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowType == GridViewRowType.EditForm)
    {
        var gridView = sender as ASPxGridView;
        var companyID = gridView.GetMasterRowKeyValue();
        var ddlCompany = gridView.FindEditFormTemplateControl("ddlCompany") as ASPxComboBox;
        ddlCOmpany.SelectedValue = companyID;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this, but now there is an error. When I click new button it says "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I think ddlCompany is null. How to overcome this?

Comment: re you using EditFormTemplate? or inline editing? as i mentioned, if you are using Inline Edit Fields, you need to use CellEditorInitialize. Ive updated the answer to illustrate it

Comment: It works but there are still some little problems. (e.Editor as ASPxComboBox).SelectedIndex =  grid.GetMasterRowKeyValue(); doesn't match because SelectedIndex is object, GetMasterRowKeyValue is integer. So I put (int) in front of grid.GetMasterRowKeyValue. However, combobox shows wrong companies, usually the company which has the last ID.

Comment: it was a type, it should be 'SelectedValue'  instead of 'SelectedIndex'. Answer is updated ...

Comment: It should be only 'Value', not 'SelectedValue'. The problem is totally solved. Thank you for your help.